# How to get the tagname of a custom element from the outside (or even inside)?

Tags: typescript, web-component, custom-element, lit-element, lit

My current approach:

Custom Element:

```js
@customElement("bb-flow-identification")
export class FlowIdentification extends LitElement { /*...*/ }
```

Other location:

```js
import { FlowIdentification } from "./flow-identification";

// The following yields the name of the class, e.g. 'FlowIdentification'
console.log(FlowIdentification.name);
```

How can I get the `bb-flow-identification` tagname from the 'Other location' file? And if that does not work, can I somehow access it from the 'Custom Element' file?

PS: This question is not specific to lit, but I'm having the problem too in the lit framework.

Comment: if you have a Node reference, its ``n.nodeName`` (uppercase) and ``n.localName`` (lowercase) But I have an inkling this is not your question. ``FlowIndentification`` is a class definition, not a Custom Element, if you have ``foo = Array()`` then you can't ask Array either for the name foo

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Ah shit... I think I get my error in thought. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: You can delete your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rely on plain JavaScript semantics.

```
export const ELEM_NAME = "bb-flow-identification";

@customElement(ELEM_NAME)
export class FlowIdentification extends LitElement {

  static registeredName = ELEM_NAME;
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
// Usage
import { FlowIdentification, ELEM_NAME } from "./flow-identification";


// Option 1
console.log(ELEM_NAME);

// Option 2
console.log(FlowIdentification.registeredName);
```

Comment: I accepted this, as this is probably the closest to perfection we can achieve. Just chose one way out of those two of course, but both seem reasonable. Thanks!